# Why "vertical-align: middle;" doesn't work with "min-height"?

Tags: html, css

When I set min-height and "vertical-align: middle;" the text is not aligned vertically. 
First example: http://jsfiddle.net/pkaXR/ 
How should I change css align image and text vertically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min-height` sets the minimum height of a *block*.

`vertical-align` sets the position of inline content *on a line*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like http://jsfiddle.net/rPsEJ/26/ - I'm not sure I understood the question right though. ;-) As far as I know, vertical-align only applies to table cells.